# Problem with reading bit data type from MySQL and transformation into Redshift with AWS Glue

Tags: mysql, pyspark, aws-glue

I have a table in a MySQL Database that contains a column called `activity` which is of data type BIT. When converted to INT it can take on the values 1,2 or 3.

When using the crawler in AWS Glue it recognizes `activity` as BOOLEAN. I have tried to edit the schema for the table and change data type for `activity` to INT but Glue still reads it as BOOLEAN when running the job.

I have also tried to use ApplyMapping to convert it to INT but with no success.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by pushing down an query to the MySQL database where I CAST the BIT as INT when reading it into Glue using:

```
pushdown_query = "(SELECT col1, CAST(activity AS INT) AS activity FROM my_table) my_table"

df = glueContext.read.format("jdbc")\
.option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") \
.option("url", db_url) \
.option("dbtable", pushdown_query) \
.option("user", db_user) \
.option("password", db_pass).load()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use instead spark/pySpark code to read the table in your MySQL Database.
For example, using pySpark will be as follow:

```
jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql://{0}:{1}/{2}".format(jdbcHostname, jdbcPort, jdbcDatabase)
connectionProperties = {
  "user" : jdbcUsername,
  "password" : jdbcPassword,
  "driver" : "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
}
employees_table = spark.read.jdbc(jdbcUrl, "employees", connectionProperties)
```

You can find more information on this link: [Spark Data Sources](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/sql-databases.html#)
Hopefully, spark will do a much better job than AWS Glue on inferring the schema.

Comment: I have already tried to use that approch with `spark.read.format('jdbc')` but it still reads the column as boolean. Any other suggestion?

Comment: First of all, your source column `activity` should be an INT instead of BIT if its values are 1,2,3, etc. Usually, the type BIT is used for boolean values so, that's why probably keeps reading it as a boolean. Besides that, you can also try to change the data type on the metadata before writing to Redshift. https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/aws/amazon-redshift.html#setting-a-custom-column-type

Comment: Yes, but the source column is an INT due to other application use cases. I on the other hand what to use it for BI and analysis purposes. I have also tried to change the metadata before writing to Redshift. The problem is still that the `activity` column is recognized as BOOLEN when read from the database. So when I then try to transform it to INT it only transforms True/False to 1/0. Is there some other approach I can use in order to solve this? I'm really grateful for your help.

Comment: In my case, the data type is "tinyint". Still AWS Glue considers it as boolean. Any way to handle this?

Comment: @SujaiSivasamy - add `?tinyInt1isBit=false` to your connection string like: `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?tinyInt1isBit=false`